# É possível escolher entre arquivos .hex armazenados no sd do arduino?

Tags: arduino

eu trabalhei em um projeto embarcado que altera os módulos de diferentes funções, mas o código do programa para o arduino mega é muito grande para integrar todas as funções dos módulos e para reescreve-lo, pesquisei vi e testei que é possivel iniciar o arquivo .hex do Sd, então eu me perguntei se eu posso configurar o bootloader para determinar o módulo que o sistema está usando para que ele possa mudar entre os arquivos .hex armazenados no SD. Alguém já fez alguma coisa parecida?